# Rails project with React Rails directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

[Image showing my rails structure for react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc72M.png)

I have a lot of react components and wish to simply keep them better organized. So I'll cut to the chase and just ask. Is it possible to put my react components in directories and if so- how do I select them in a view and other react components?

I've already tried a few variatians like the one below without success and fear that it's simply not possible? Can't find any documentation about this either.

```
<%= react_component('OutfitCreate.Images') %>
```

Edit: To clarify, I want to make it clear that I'm using a typical rails project structure, and for react I am making use of the react-rails gem to handle my components as well as generating them.

Edit2: To clarify further, what I'm seeking is a way to target a react component by directory as such:

```
<%= react_component('<directory>/<classname>') %>
```

where each directory will be sub directories of "components".

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but maybe it helps anyone. You can do it like this:

`<%= react_component "ComponentFolder/ComponentClassName" %>`

It works just fine with rails-react and webpacker.

Comment: didn't work for me. I have a component in subdirectory like `users/Users.js`. When I `<%= react_component "users/Users" %>, it raise an error which says "can not find component "users/Users".

Comment: is this the full path app/javascript/components/users/Users.js?

Comment: Your answer is correct. My case is caused by other errors. Thanks

Comment: working as well with `folder_name/ComponentName`, there was another error showed only as `[Webpacker] Compilation failed` without details

Answer (score 0):

React components will be considered **global**, because all *.js* will be minified in one single big *.js* file. So, you will have to take some considerations.

---

First, in your sprockets file (Normally *application.js*) you need to tell Rails to serve the *React Components* you want. The easy way would be to require all folders and files in *components* folder, because all your components will be there, but organized in subfolders. This is made adding the next line:

```
// File: app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require_tree ./components
```

Second, if you want to use your *React component* named for example **Images**, which could be defined in `../components/folder/images.js`, you just could use in your *Rails View* the helper `react_component('Images')` like usual.

React will find the **Images component** if it match with the *Images component* you defined inside some served *.js* (But a sane human will expect you defined the *Image Component* inside some *images.js*) because this name *Images* is global (Remember? One big .js file will be served).

With this approach, the client will download only one big .js file with all your React Components. Bad for download speed, but could be cached.

So, here, you would have to take care to name all components with a different name each one.

---

Now, if you have for example a component named **Foo** inside `../components/folder/doesnt_matter.js` and another component with the same name **Foo**, but inside `../components/another_folder/this_neither.js`, you will have to tell Rails which file do you want to serve for the specific View you want to render to evade collision name problems.

This means, you could make the client to download only the needed js code (and the needed React Components) for the rendered page. It will be downloading .js files for each page, losing the cache possibility.

One intermediate way to do this, would be to serve a middle sized .js file for all the views in the same controller.

To do this, you could organize your js (or jsx, or ...) in a way you could have a place for common Components (which are used in two or more controllers), and a specific folder for each controller with specific React Components in there.

First, you will have to replace the previously added `//require_tree ./components` in *application.js* with `//require ./components/common/` for serving only the common React components to *All Views*.

Second, in your *layout*, you could serve **two** js files; an *application.js* and a `#{controller_name}.js` (This means, one specific .js file per controller).

Third, for **each** controller, you will have a *.js* file with the same name. So, supose you have a controller called *home_controller*, then, you will need to have a *home.js* (controller_name helper in layout view will make rails to look for this file) and in it, using sprockets again, you will serve specific React Components with `//require ./components/home/`

In this way, you will have to take care of your organization, and the React Components Names need to differ with the ones inside `.../components/common/`.

---

If you want to be more specific yet, you could use the same technique in layout in combination with `controller_name` and `action_name` helpers. Or you could use `content_for` asking for the specific .js files that have the React Components the View needs.

However, you need to be carefull because i don't know how crazy the Assets Pipeline could turn against you. Specially using `content_for`.

Answer (score -1):

I recently used the [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) and had a good experience. It takes care of accessing your components in Rails templates and does a few other nice things.

To answer your question specifically, you can put your components inside as many directories as you like as long as you follow the gem docs. The gem provides a view helper that allows you to render a specific component, and to pass data to it as props (the helper takes a hash which becomes the component's props).

Edit -- I'm not sure if you're already using the gem, the helper method you are using looks like it, but you don't specifically mention it. Perhaps there is a problem with the gem installation and/or setup. You need to edit `application.js` and also to run the generator task: `rails g react:install`

Edit -- To make sure you can access components in the components subdirectory, you should do the following things:

*run the generator: `rails g react:install`

*make sure the generated components.js file contains: `//= require_tree ./components`

*make sure your application.js file contains:

`//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components`

Comment: Sorry. To clarify- yes I am already using the react-rails gem, and I'm generating the react components like this "rails g react:component <name> --es6".

Comment: You said that as long as I follow the gem docs? Could you elaborate more spesifically with an example as to how I can access my components that I've placed within sub directories to the "components" directory? By default my generated components will be placed in the "components" directory, but I wish to have several directories within the "components" directory. Hope this wasn't too confusing, but feel free to ask and I'll try to clarify again.

Comment: My guess is the gem is set up improperly -- components placed in the `components` directory should be accessible to you. I've updated my answer with some more details about the setup. Have you done these things, and are you still having issues?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you understand my problem. Might be due to my poor explaination. However, in short. I have no problem accessing my react components in views and other components. My problem is that I can't access them by directory. Like. If I have two components named images.es6.jsx and they are in two directories like: 'new' and 'edit', I am unable to access the spesific component by using the directory to access it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I believe I have misunderstood. Your react components are going to be named according to the name of the actual exported class. It's a good practice to have the file name match the actual component name as defined in JS. The directory structure is not meaningful in terms of names. It's just for organization. You should probably not have two components with the same name. Also, generally in react I wouldn't have different components for new and edit forms. I'd have a form component that can handle both

Comment: To get around your immediate problem you could have a NewImage and an EditImage component, and just reference them with the helper using the unique name. But I think this is probably not the React way of doing things. React thinks in terms of components, so one image form component could do both, and you'd probably handle that by passing in an image record as props. Hope this helps!

Comment: I see your points, and I am already using I guess the same solution as you came up with- by calling my components something slightly different from one another. The main reason I want to be able to target them by directory is simply to keep things organized and avoid long component names when things get pretty nested. I like to keep my components small to keep things very component based and thus a lot of components are made hehe. Tell me if you find a way to target by directory, otherwise thanks for your time so far :) It's been intellectual, and naming them slightly different is good for now

Comment: Sure, no problem! Would you mind accepting my answer if you found it helpful? I think it's good to try to keep components small, but I think maybe you should think of a different way to break them down, and how to re-use things like form components across multiple parts of the app. have fun!